# Volley ImageLoader isCached method always returns false

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley ImageLoader for downloading the image from URI.

Here is my Implementation

BitmapLruCache.java

```
public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {

    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 6;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public BitmapLruCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

VolleyHelper.java

```
public class VolleyHelper {

    private static final int MAX_IMAGE_CACHE_ENTIRES  = 100;
    private static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private VolleyHelper() {
    }

    public static void init(Context context) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new BitmapLruCache(MAX_IMAGE_CACHE_ENTIRES));
    }

    public static RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            return mRequestQueue;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("RequestQueue not initialized");
        }
    }

    public static ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        if (mImageLoader != null) {
            return mImageLoader;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ImageLoader not initialized");
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
ImageLoader mImageLoader = VolleyHelper.getImageLoader();

if (mImageLoader.isCached(url, maxWidth, maxheight)) {
   //always false
}
```

It downloads the image and displays it properly. But `isCached` method returns `false` even though image is cached. And i am not sure what should be the values for arguments `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

i went through the documentation and i found that

```
/**
     * Checks if the item is available in the cache.
     * @param requestUrl The url of the remote image
     * @param maxWidth The maximum width of the returned image.
     * @param maxHeight The maximum height of the returned image.
     * @return True if the item exists in cache, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isCached(String requestUrl, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        throwIfNotOnMainThread();

        String cacheKey = getCacheKey(requestUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight);
        return mCache.getBitmap(cacheKey) != null;
    }
```

so it means that image was not cashed properly

for documentation visit https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/2952b728becbf317f88a627cf17d0b5b6645bb66/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java

and http://files.evancharlton.com/volley-docs/

Comment: k i am looking in to it

Comment: Thanks..but I think Image was cached properly...problem is with the `maxWidth` and `maxheight` i guess..do you have any idea what those values should be?

Comment: while you are retrieving images first time at that moment whatever width, height you are using , save them and use them here!!

Comment: If you don't specify `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` when requesting an image, you should call `isCached` with 0 for both.

Comment: If you're absolutely sure that the URL is identical in both calls, then perhaps it is a bug in Volley. You should debug it and follow the calls. If you do find a bug (on their side) you can submit it or perhaps make a pull request with the fix.